# Why this page is so SLOW on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, google-chrome

[This](http://www.gabbatracklistworld.com/test.php) is the page I mean. Try to click on the links (Add Side/Track, Remove) and you can see my own grind to add/remove some input text.

1. With Chrome : no problem;
2. With IE (7) : no problem;
3. With Firefox (4) : Oh my god, the whole interface is very slow.

The Javascript/jQuery code (as you can see) is really short, and there are nothing so complex.
Why this behaviour?

Comment: Not slow for me, try disabling extensions

Comment: No problem here on Firefox 3.6 on Linux.

Comment: Upgrading to jQuery 1.6.1 (latest) instead using 1.5.x will improve speed... but it all goes down to the script engine in the browser, and keep in mind that FF does a lot more stuff (that we dont need) in the back. Chrome and Safari are the quickest.

Comment: i tried on FF 4.0.1 and is fine... which version you are using

Comment: Just tested the page in Firefox 4 and Chrome and noticed no difference (they are both equally fast).

Comment: No problem here on 4.0.1 on Mac

Comment: @balexandre - V8 is the fastest! :)

Comment: @Kevin wait until they have a V10 engine on the bonnet! :D

Comment: Have you tried restarting Firefox? FF4 still slowly accumulates memory and slows to a crawl when it's grown too large.

Comment: I'm using 4.0.1, just installed on windows 7, and really, the differences is BIG. Maybe I try to restart the pc, but I don't think that's the problem...

Comment: tested in 3.6.15 in Windows XP and it works like charm.

Comment: a-ok here on windows 7 ff 4.0.1

Comment: Tried to restart the pc : nothing change. the page is like a lollipop...

Comment: I don't understand why close=4?

Comment: I've tried FF 4.01, IE8, Chrome and Safari - No problems for me - all seem as fast as each other

Comment: No problem when Tested in firefox 4 - but check the firebug panel console for some errors committed in your jquery selector.

Comment: @all : so let me understand : the fludir of the fadeIn() effect is the same from chrome to ff? How is possible that I see the effect on FF so slow? uhm...

Comment: Why have you close thios thread? Really I don't understand...

Comment: Tryed the 3.16.17 version : it's ALL ok :O So a problem with 4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiling indicates the clones are really slow. Have you tried manually creating the elements with a fixed DOM string (instead of using `.clone()`) and using delegates for the event handling? That'd probably improve overall performance a lot, in any browser.

Edit: and by manually, I mean something like:

```
var newElem = $('<div class="trackOn">...</div>');
```

Then for the events:

```
tracklistOnElem.delegate('.trackBotton .addSide', 'click', function() { addSide(this); return false; });
tracklistOnElem.delegate('.trackBotton .addTrack', 'click', function() { addTrack(this); return false; });
```

etc.

Edit #2: Reading the docs always pays off, here too: http://api.jquery.com/clone/ says that in jQuery 1.5.0, the default for copying events and data was incorrectly set to `true`. It's back to `false` again in 1.5.1 and friends, so try using jQuery 1.6.0 or 1.5.2. That will probably also help. You can also modify the clone() calls to manually specify `false` as the first and only parameter, to avoid this happening again.

Comment: yeah, but that's ridicolous the performance is so slow for a single clone(). There are somethings wrong...

Comment: What do you mean as "manually creating the elements with a fixed DOM string"? A single HTML element that I clone is about 50-60 line, it's hard to put it in a string :(

Comment: It's having to clone all the descendant elements, and you have those big selects in each row, so those make them slow (because it has to check for events etc. on each of those). Really, try creating a static string and just re-generating the DOM from that, it'll be a lot faster.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from using a variable and a for loop to string together all those <option> elements, without having one giant static string stuck in the page. :-)

Comment: Tried, nothing change with jQuery 1.6.1. To be honest, yes I should use your tips for load element, without clone. But this is not the fault of my script (really, it's too slow). I see on Firefox that the rest of page/etc is really slow. For example just scroll that page from top to the button, it snaps :O I think it's a compatibility problem with this version. I'll try an older one...

Comment: In fact, the firefox 3.6.17 works perfectly :O Very strange...

Answer (score 2):

I tried the YSlow add-on for the Firebug add-on.  One thing that jumped out at me was:

> Grade F on Reduce the number of DOM elements
>
> There are 3203 DOM elements on the page
>
> A complex page means more bytes to download, and it also means slower DOM access in JavaScript. Reduce the number of DOM elements on the page to improve performance.
>
> Read More: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#min_dom

Perhaps building the DOM elements in javascript after page load would help.